# Removing lines with only digits - regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am new to both python and regex. I am trying to process a text file where I want to remove lines with only digits and space. This is the regular expression I am using.

```
^\s*[0-9]*\s*$
```

I am able to match the lines I want to remove (in notepad++ find dialog).

but when I try to do the same with python, the lines are not matched. Is there a problem in the regex itself or there is some problem with my python code?

Python code that I am using :

```
contacts = re.sub(r'^\s*[0-9]*\s*$','\n',contents)
```

Sample text

```
Age:30
Gender:Male



20 


Name:संगीता शर्मा
HusbandsName:नरेश कुमार शर्मा
HouseNo:10/183
30 30
Gender:Female


21 

Name:मोनू शर्मा
FathersName:कैलाश शर्मा
HouseNo:10/183
30
Gender:Male
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` in multiline mode:

```
contacts = re.sub(r'^\s*([0-9]+\s*)+$','\n',x, flags=re.M)
```

### Demo

If you want the beginning `^` and ending `$` anchors to kick in, then you want to be in multiline mode.

In addition, use the following to represent a line only containing clusters of numbers, possibly separated by whitespace:

```
^\s*([0-9]+\s*)+$
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need regex for that, a simple [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to remove characters you're not interested and check if something is left should more than suffice:

```
import string

clear_chars = string.digits + string.whitespace  # a map of characters we'd like to check for

# open input.txt for reading, out.txt for writing
with open("input.txt", "rb") as f_in, open("output.txt", "wb") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:  # iterate over the input file line by line
        if line.translate(None, clear_chars):  # remove the chars, check if anything is left
            f_out.write(line)  # write the line to the output file
        # uncomment the following if you want added newlines when pattern matched
        # else:
        #     f_out.write("\n")  # write a new line on match
```

Which will produce for your sample input:

```
Age:30
Gender:Male
Name:संगीता शर्मा
HusbandsName:नरेश कुमार शर्मा
HouseNo:10/183
Gender:Female
Name:मोनू शर्मा
FathersName:कैलाश शर्मा
HouseNo:10/183
Gender:Male
```

If you want the matching lines replaced with a new line, just uncomment the `else` clause.